# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before & token

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I'm getting a mysterious error in my project that says:

> expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion

It's not allowing me to use my overloaded `operator<<`. This previously worked before I made my class (`myVector`) into a `template`

```
//MyVector class
//An implementation of a vector of integers.
template <class T>
class MyVector{
public:
    //Purpose: Initialize an object of type MyVector
    //Parameters: none.
    //Returns: nothing.
    MyVector();

    //------------------------------------------------
    //Purpose: Initialize an object of type MyVector
    //Parameters: an integer.
    //Returns: nothing.
    //------------------------------------------------
    MyVector(int);

    //Purpose: Destroys objects of type MyVector
    //Parameters: none.
    //Returns: nothing
    //------------------------------------------------
    ~MyVector();

    //Purpose: Returns the current size of the MyVector.
    //Parameters: none.
    //Returns: the size.
    int size() const;

    //------------------------------------------------
    //Purpose: Returns the capacity of the MyVector.
    //Parameters: none.
    //Returns: int.
    int capacity() const;

    //------------------------------------------------
    //Purpose: Removes the entries of MyVector.
    //Parameters: none.
    //Returns: nothing.
    void clear();

    //------------------------------------------------
    //Purpose: Appends a given integer to the vector.
    //Parameters: an integer.
    //Returns: nothing.
    void push_back(T);

    //------------------------------------------------
    //Purpose: Shows what's at a given position.
    //Parameters: an integer index.
    //Returns: an integer.
    T at(int) const;

    MyVector(const MyVector& b);
    const MyVector& operator=(const MyVector&);

    //------------------------------------------------

private:
    int _size;
    int _capacity;
    int* head;

    //Purpose: Increases the capacity of a MyVector when it's 
    // capacity is equal to it's size. Called by push_back(int)
    //Parameters/Returns: nothing.
    void increase();

    //Purpose: Copies the given vector reference. 
    //Param: MyVector reference.
    //Returns: nothing.
    void copy(const MyVector&);

    //Purpose: Frees MyVector up for an assignment.
    void free();
};

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const MyVector<T>);
//This line is giving me the error.

#endif
```

I have the code for the operator in a seperate file:

```
template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyVector<T> V){
    int N = V.size();
    os << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        os << V.at(i)<<endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

I've looked at other questions, but none seem to match mine. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `using std::ostream;` or a `using namespace std;` (yuck) somewhere?  If not, the compiler isn't going to have any idea what `ostream` is.

Comment: Can someone squeeze the formatting of the above code please ?

Comment: explain where you have defined the template class. In the same file or a different file.

Comment: Comments should tell us what's not obvious. You don't need us to tell what the purpose of the default ctor is, or its parameters, or its return value. The Purpose comment for `increase` is a good one. The worst part is all the places where the comments are outdated when you made this a tamplate but forgot to update the comments; those are quite confusing now,

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to qualify `ostream` with `std` as:

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MyVector<T>);`

And you should almost certainly be passing your vector by const reference, rather than const value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a template in a file and then define it into another file. You can only define it.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Yes, you can. But even if you couldn't, it wouldn't cause the error message reported here.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the operator<< function accept a constant reference to the `MyVector` rather than just a constant, since what you are doing is to create a copy of the vector to pass into the function.

```
template <class T> std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const MyVector<T>& V)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion suggests that it does not recognize ostream as a type (ie, it has not been declared in this scope). Prefixing with std:: is not alone sufficient to resolve the issue; you must also include the dependent file.

```
#include <ostream>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to **Declare** this:

```
template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const MyVector<T>);
```

You can follow this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
A();
int _size;
};
template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const A<T> p)
{
cout<<"in ostream"<<endl;
}
template <class T>
A<T>::A()
{
_size = 90;
cout<<_size<<endl;
}
int main()
{
A<int> ob;
cout<<ob;
return 0;
}
```